# getting a NoMethodError (undefined method `photo_url' for #<PhotosController:0x00007fb6e5b80558>): with rails and I can't find the solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api

I am trying to upload photos to my rails backend but I get the error mentioned above.

Here's the controller

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  def index
    @photos = Photo.where(drink_id: params[:drink_id])

    render json: @photos
  end

  # GET /photos/1
  def show
    render json: @photo
  end

  # POST /photos
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

    if @photo.save
      render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo
    else
      render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1
  def update
    if @photo.update(photo_params)
      render json: @photo
    else
      render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /photos/1
  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:name, :src, :drink_id)
    end
end
```

Here's the schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_01_12_230812) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "drinks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "base"
    t.string "waves"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "shop"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "src"
    t.bigint "drink_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["drink_id"], name: "index_photos_on_drink_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "photos", "drinks"
end
```

This is where I upload the photo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {getAllDrinks,uploadDrink, uploadPhoto } from './services/api-helper'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    allDrinks: null,
    drinkPhotos: null,
    formData: {

    }
    
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let allDrinks = await getAllDrinks();
    this.setState({
      allDrinks
    });
  }

  // lets user select image from their own files
  // sets state as the selected file
  // turns file into a readable url for src in an img tag
  fileChangedHandler = event => {
    let reader = new FileReader()
     reader.onload = (e) => {
       this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.result})
     }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
    console.log(reader)
  }

    // sets state for formData based off of user input
    handleChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        formData: {
          ...prevState.formData,
          [name]: value
        }
      }));
    }
  
     // adds this.state.selectedFile (users selected image) to this.state.formData
  // saves formData to the data base
 uploadHandler = () => {
   uploadDrink(this.state.formData)
   window.location.reload()
 }
  
  photoUploadHandler = () => {
    this.state.formData.src = `${this.state.selectedFile}`
    console.log(this.state.formData)
    uploadPhoto( this.state.formData.drink_id, this.state.formData)
    // window.location.reload()
  }
  

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div class='upload-section'>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='name' name='name'>
        </input>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='base' name='base'>
      </input>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='waves' name='waves'>
      </input>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='description' name='description'>
      </input>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='shop' name='shop'>
  </input>
        <button onClick={this.uploadHandler}>Upload!</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class='upload-section'>
      <input type="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler} name='src'>
          </input>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='name' name='name'>
          </input>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='drink reference' name='drink_id'>
          </input>
        <button onClick={this.photoUploadHandler}>Upload!</button>
      </div>
      <div id='delete-section'>
          {this.state.allDrinks ?
            this.state.allDrinks.map(drink=> (
              <div className='info-box'>

                <p>{drink.name }</p>
              </div>
            ))
            :
            <></>
        }
      </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
 
}

export default App;
```

I've been racking my brain for days now and can't figure out where the error comes from, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the code block for `uploadPhoto` function?

Comment: `export const uploadPhoto = async (id, formData) => {
  const resp = await api.post(`/drinks/${id}/photos`, formData)
  return resp.data;
}`

Comment: path looks correct to me. somewhere you should be using `photo_url` instead of `photos_url`. could you please provide complete error log?